# The difference between $\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S´/\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{\bar X-\mu}{s´/\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Imagine we're dealing with a normal population, with known mean $\mu$, but unknown variance $\sigma^2$.

We know that $\frac{\bar X-\mu}{S'/\sqrt{n}}\sim t(n-1)$. (T-Student distribution)

Now, suppose someone asks us to calculate $P(\bar X >c)$ and give us $s'=3$.

I've seen people write the following: $P(\bar X >c)=P(\frac{\bar X-\mu}{s'/\sqrt{n}}<\frac{c-\mu}{s'/\sqrt{n}})=P(T>\frac{c-\mu}{s'/\sqrt{n}})$, where $T\sim t(n-1)$. This sequence of equalities doesn't seem to be correct, since a draw of $S'$, i.e. $s'$, is not the same as the r.v.  $S'$. If it's correct, why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $S'$?

Comment: @zhoraster it's the standard error with the bessel correction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Formula

Comment: The mean is known, so it is quite weird to use it here.

Comment: @zhoraster the example is a bit artificial. But I made it up to justify something I've seen done (wrong?) several times... $S'^2$ is just the unbiased sample variance.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I'll try to write my thoughts in a couple of minutes.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. It seems that the question you're interested in is finding the *conditional* probability $P_{\sigma^2}(\overline X>c\mid S'=s')$. Note first that it depends on unknown $\sigma$. It is well known that for a Gaussian sample, the sample mean $\overline X$ and the sample variance $S'$ are independent. So knowing $S'$ should not help, as $P_{\sigma^2}(\overline X>c\mid S'=s') = P_{\sigma^2}(\overline X>c)$.

Comment: @zhoraster thanks for your comments. I still have some doubts. Could you please write an answer instead? Because some moderator may come and remove your comments, by stating that the comment section is not for an extended conversation. I couldn't understand from your comment stating $P(T<k|var)$ is constant and onwards...

Comment: Never mind, the second part was not totally correct. Should think a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, these people are mistaken.

Let us try to follow their "reasoning". Since $T = \frac{\overline X - \mu}{S'/\sqrt{n}}$ has the $t(n-1)$ distribution, then for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
P_{\sigma^2}(T>x) =  P(t(n-1) >x).
$$
So in order to compute $P(\overline X> c)$, we plug in $x = \frac{c - \mu}{s'/\sqrt{n}}$ in there and get the answer. Right? Wrong!

Essentially, this line of reasoning relies on equality 
$$
P_{\sigma^2}\left(T>\frac{c - \mu}{S'/\sqrt{n}}\right) = P\big(t(n-1) > x\big)\big|_{x=\frac{c - \mu}{S'/\sqrt{n}}},
$$
which is absurd (the left-hand side is non-random, while the right-hand side is random).

---

Here is a much simpler example, which I think is more illustrative. Let $X,Y$ be independent having the distribution $P(X= a) = 1-P(X=- a) = 0.1$ with unknown $a>0$. You observe $X=x$. What is the probability that $Y>0$?

Using a similar "reasoning", you might say that, no matter what $a$ is, $Y/X= 1$ with probability $0.82$ and $-1$ with probability $0.18$. "Therefore", $P(Y>0) = 0.82$ when $x>0$ and $P(Y>0)=0.18$ when $x<0$. Right? No way!

Of course, $P(Y>0) = 0.1$ *always*, independently of $x$.

Comment: would there be a way to solve $P(\bar X >c)$ using the t-distribution?

I've just found an exercise where I have to solve something similar.